# How can I update a database MSSQL 2005 Express record using the ID field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, vbscript

How can I update a database MSSQL 2005 Express record using the ID field and using VBScript?

I have a script in VBScript:

```vb
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & & Klient_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" '"
```

But to update the record in the `Klienci_NC.Klient` in MSSQL database `Klienci_NC` I have to type in the box `ID_zmienna` given number representing the record ID column.

What to do variable it is automatically downloaded to the box?

All my VBScipt script looks like this:

```vb
Dim conn, SQL, rs
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=DJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Baza_NC;user id ='user_baza_nc';password='password'"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
rem myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = 'Hello'"
rem myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "'"

myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = '" & ID_zmienna & "'"

myCommand.Execute
myConn.Close
```

What to do to update the selected record in the database, and not all?

Comment: [Beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: If your question is how to automatically fill the variable `ID_zmienna`: we cannot answer that question since we know nothing about your database structure (or your application).

Answer (score 0):

In this line, the concatenation not correct

```
    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & & Klient_niceform' 'WHERE Klienci_NC.ID =' "& ID_zmienna &" '"
```

This is loosing your where clause off the end of the statement, making the command update every row in your table.

**It needs to be like this:**

```
    myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = '" & ID_zmienna & "'"
```

Also, Zohar's comment is highly relevant. This method of concatenating variables into SQL is open to SQL Injection attacks. Consider using the ADO.NET SQLCommand with Parameter objects.

Comment: Yes it is open but the user and pwd are in the file in clear text so that's the least of their worries.

Comment: thanks for the answer. In this whole script is the correct entry. does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: If every record in the database is being updated then it is likely that the WHERE clause is being lost somehow. This is normally down to bugs in concatenation. The best thing to do if you need to analyse further is to open up SQL Server Profiler and capture the SQL your script is generating. Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ8Dyv4Uk6E. Profiler is a core tool for debugging these sorts of problems.